# Running SVN installed in a different machine

Tags: svn, shell, unix

Let's say we have two UNIX machines A and B:
Machine A has svn installed.
Machine B cannot have svn installed.

I want to "SVN export" one directory from my subversion repository to machine B. One way of doing this would be running a script in A (through SSH) that does "SVN export" to a local directory and then rsync it with machine B.

Is there a easier way of doing this?

Comment: Why it "cannot have svn installed"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you setup additional services on machin A?
Because if so, you could setup a NFS server to share files from A to B; then you would only have to perform the svn export in the shared directory, and grab the data using nfs client on B.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a easier way of doing this?

Unless you can mount a directory from machine B on machine A (or vice versa), `rsync` seems a pretty straightforward means of doing it.